# How to show icons without text in QListWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, icons, qlistwidget

I want to show only icons in my `QListWidget`. I set text to empty string. When I select an icon I see an empty selected square on the text place. See the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get rid of this empty space?!

Answer (score 9):

use NULL instead

`ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":/res/icon"),NULL));`

Answer (score 5):

How do you add an icon in your QListWidget? This should work fine (I am loading the icon from the resource file) :

```
ui->listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(":/res/icon"), ""));
```

**EDIT**

From the screenshot I see that your problem is that there is some white space below the icon corresponding to the empty string. You could hack this behavior by setting a very small size to the font of the list widget item.

```
QListWidgetItem *newItem = new QListWidgetItem;
QFont f;
f.setPointSize(1); // It cannot be 0
newItem->setText("");
newItem->setIcon(QIcon(":/res/icon"));
newItem->setFont(f);
ui->listWidget->addItem(newItem);
```

This will do the trick. However you could also use the [`setItemWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) function and use your custom designed widget, or use a `QListView` and a delegate.

Comment: An empty space is shown instead the text. This space is selected when you select the icon. I want to get rid of it. Corrected my question.

Comment: Setting small font doesn't do the trick. A small rectangle is still visible after selection. setItemWidget works strangely, it still displays an empty rectangle. I have added QLabel with a pixmap as widget. The last hope is the delegate. Can you post a code snippet, how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905147/qt-qlistwidgetitem-multiple-lines). You have to reimplement the paint function and the size hint. In your case you will only add an icon the way you want it. Then you just call the [setItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate).

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to call setSizeHint() on the item with the size of the icon.  I added a little padding because the selection box was cut off without it.

```
QListWidgetItem * pItem = new QListWidgetItem(icon, "");
pItem->setSizeHint(iconSize + QSize(4,4));
listWidget->addItem(pItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution where you do want to store text (as an identifier) **but not show it**, is not to set ANY text for the `QListWidgetItem`s in the creator but instead store the text details in the `data` part.

Specifically you want to use this [`QListWidgetItem(QListWidget *parent = nullptr, int type = Type)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidgetitem.html#QListWidgetItem) constructor that can be used without any arguments. Then you can assign an icon, **but no text** afterwards, before inserting it into the `QListWidget`.

If you are putting the text in afterwards anyhow you'd be using `QListWidgetItem::setText(const QString &text)` and you just need to change that to `QListWidgetItem::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)` which in practice would be `QListWidgetItem::setData(Qt::UserRole, const QString &text)` and rely on a `QString` being convertible to a `QVariant`. Unfortunately there are some shortcomings going the other way:

- To retrieve the value you need to explicitly convert the `QVariant` back to a `QString` - by using `QListWidgetItem::data(Qt::UserRole)->toString()`
- To search for a particular match Qt does not provide a `find` means to identify the index(es) of the members of a `QListWidget` that match a particular *role* though it does for the original text - unlike, say a `QComboBox` which has `findXXXX` methods for both.

The project I code for had exactly this issue (we had unwanted text at the bottom which was set to a font size of `1` but it still showed up) which I eventually fixed like this and it works:

[image: Screenshot from Mudlet application showing a QListWidget filled with QListWidgetItems but with no text underneath them]