# Video memory usage of QLabel and the effects of QWidget::hide()

Tags: qt, video-memory

I am writing an application and there will potentially be tens of thousands of labels (a log-viewing application of a sort), most of them hidden with QWidget::hide(). I imagine a QLabel, when created, takes up some video memory. Now, does hide() free that video memory? Or will I have to QWidget::remove() most of those hidden labels to keep video memory usage at a reasonable level?

Comment: If you done with your `QLabel` just remove it. why you want to hide it? do you want to show it later?

Comment: @Simon I want to show some of them later (I don't know which ones though). So if I remove a label, I might have to create/position it once again later on.

Comment: Have you considered to use QListView with custom delegate instead of labels? List view guarantees that only visible items are drawn, and it does positioning and scrolling for you.

Comment: Just an opinion but, using tens of thousands of `QLabel`s (assuming that's what tou mean) for this isn't a good idea.  If you really require that number of distinct visual entities then you might want to look at the [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) instead.  Although, you mention a log viewing application in which case the model/view framework might be more appropriate.

Comment: @AlexanderZavertan thanks for mentioning it. QListView has a lot, but it appears to be that some things will be very tough to customize there for what I have in mind. Moreover, I don't see how it can manage the video memory issue. Does it have a special automatic mechanism for removing the rows that are very far away from the video memory?

Comment: @G.M. I didn't know about the framework you have linked, thank you for it! It can do scrolling for me, but that's not a big issue I have. I basically have a QVBoxLayout, with a bunch of widgets and each widget might contain a bunch of labels. And I need to scroll through that. Btw, why is this not a good idea? Different labels might have different background/text colors. It's what I have to do as far as I see.

Comment: Using a huge number of labels probably isn't a good idea simply because of the resources it will use.  A `QWidget` isn't huge in terms of memory usage but it's not exactly lightweight either -- hence my concern.  Note also that different background and/or text colours can easily br achieved with the [model/view framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) (e.g. `QListView`) as suggested by @AlexanderZavertan .

Comment: @G.M. that's my concern as well. In any case, I would like to have some control over how much info is cached in vram. I will look into using model/view framework, it might prove to be useful, so thanks for linking it. And, surely, I am still interested in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, most widgets do not store their pre-rendered images in memory. Instead, they are render themselves on demand after being invalidated. However, some do it if render is time-consuming. Took a look at QLabel source code (http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp), it seems that QLabel caches its pixmap when scaledContents is enabled and scaling is necessary. Plain text-only labels are painted as-is without any caching.

Still, as @G.M mentioned, each widget consumes some system memory to store its own data, and processing time due to event handling, so producing 10k labels is a reasonable resource waste. In contrast, item views are single widgets that draws items on their surface. No event handling overhead, no unnecessary caches. Like QLabels, item view items are perfectly stylable, see http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview, http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview for details. More complex looks like multi-line list items are achievable with QItemDelegate: [Qt QListWidgetItem Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905147/qt-qlistwidgetitem-multiple-lines)